# Checkerboard background on plot (potentially using prolog)?

Tags: plotting

Currently I have a plot of a complicated function with gridlines turned on. Is there a way to shade a checkerboard pattern of alternating colors between adjacent grid cells?

So far, I have tried passing a table of rectangles into Prolog. However, I couldn't figure out how to pass in the max/min dimensions of the plot. Moreover, this approach is ugly and cumbersome, especially if I later want to modify the location of the gridlines.

Even better, I would like to shade a custom repeating pattern, specifically the following one:

```
0 | 0
-----
1 | 0
```

where 1 denotes `{Pink, Opacity[0.1]}` and 0 denotes a white background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could make a checkerboard with [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) funtionality in [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html):

```
mesh =
 ParametricPlot[{v, u}, {u, -2, 6}, {v, 0, 20},
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &, #1 &}, 
  MeshShading -> {{RGBColor[1, 0.9, 0.9], White}, {White, White}},
  Mesh -> {8, 20},
  BoundaryStyle -> None
 ]
```

[image]

Then set it as a background with [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html):

```
Plot[5 Sinc[x], {x, 0, 20},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick},
  Prolog -> mesh[[1]]
]
```

[image]

This method is quite flexible as you have specific control over the [`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) etc.  For example with `MeshFunctions -> {Log[Abs@#2] &, Sinc[#1] &}` you get:

[image]

---

### Automation

The method above as a function for ease of application.

```
Options[addCheckerboard] =
  {MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, 
   MeshShading   -> {{RGBColor[1, 0.9, 0.9], White}, {White, White}},
   BoundaryStyle -> None};

addCheckerboard[gr_Graphics, opts : OptionsPattern[ParametricPlot]] :=
 {⌊#⌋, ⌈#2⌉} & @@@ PlotRange[gr] /. {{x_, X_}, {y_, Y_}} :>
   Show[gr,
    Prolog ->
     ParametricPlot[{u, v}, {u, x, X}, {v, y, Y},
       opts,
       Mesh -> ({X - x, Y - y} - 1),
       Evaluate @ Options @ addCheckerboard
     ][[1]]
   ]
```

You should now be able to apply this to any `Graphics` object as follows:

```
plot =
  Plot[Evaluate[Table[n^2*BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}]], {x, 0, 10},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic];

addCheckerboard[plot]
```

[image]

(`AspectRatio -> Automatic` is included in the example but not necessary for functionality.)

- You can change the fill color with `MeshShading` and the grid color with `MeshStyle`.
- You can override the regular grid with different `MeshFunctions` as above.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to use this in the situation where the x range is known, but the y range is determined based on the range of the function. In other words, the range of u in the parametric plot is unknown (as well as the first argument of `Mesh -> {8, 20}`). Would there be an easy modification to accomplish this?

Comment: There is one more issue. I need the gridlines to be placed at precisely the integers. It looks like yours are not - they are stretched to fit the range you have specified.

Comment: @pre-kidney by the way I simply have to ask: what's with the name? :^)

Comment: @pre-kidney Please see the update.

Comment: This is wonderful! But the code is a bit mysterious to me and I'm trying to learn what it's doing. Would there be a way to run it all in a single `Plot` command, without having to reference the plot and look up its properties using `PlotRange[gr]`? Essentially, I would like to do this inline without having to reference the plot later.

Comment: @pre-kidney I would be happy to try to explain any part you find opaque.  I don't believe this can all be done inside `Plot` and still have the range detected automatically.  Just in case you don't realize: you can use it like `addCheckerboard[Plot[Tan[x], {x, -2, 2}]]` without defining `plot`, but I don't think that's what you mean.  By the way I just fixed a bug.

Comment: @pre-kidney I also just realized that my implementation of the `size` parameter doesn't work.  I'll have to change that a bit too.