# How to imitate the opacity plot in EditColorFunction

Tags: plotting, color

I wish to imitate the opacity plot as shown below:

**Edit2:** (ref: https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/3d-volumetric-image-processing/edit-color-function-palette-for-image3d.html)

[image: fig 1]

Here is what I am up to now:

```
makeColorFn[colors_, opacities_, vars_] := 
  Transpose[{vars, MapThread[Append, {colors, opacities}]}] /. 
    body_ :> (Blend[body, #] &)

colors = 
  {RGBColor[0.761959, 0.470832, 0.940597], RGBColor[0.927848, 0.742785, 0.615138], 
   RGBColor[0.929162, 0.95034, 664815], RGBColor[0.431296, 0.709773, 0.927077]};

opacities = {0.632, 0.938, 0.906, 0.864};

keys = {0, 1/3, 2/3, 1};

mesh = 
  ParametricPlot[{v, u}, {v, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#2 &, #1 &}, 
    MeshShading -> {{Gray, White}, {White, Gray}}, Mesh -> {20, 20}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Intensity", Opacity}, 
    ColorFunction -> "", 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

The above code was taken from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72658/checkerboard-background-on-plot-potentially-using-prolog) and gives me the following plot:

[image: fig 2]

If I now plot the color function on top of this background,

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{keys, opacities}], 
   Prolog -> mesh[[1]], 
   Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], colors], 
   PlotRange -> Full, Filling -> Axis, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorTransferFunction[colors, opacities, keys], 
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Intensity", "Opacity"}]
```

And the corresponding result is:

[image: fig 3]

Firstly, I need the plot to be scaled accordingly as in fig 2.

Secondly, I want the control points to be colored according to the colors and opacities at those points and not a single color (blue) as I have got.

[Optional: How can I remove the checkered background above the control points?]

#### Update

I have updated the code for plotting as follows:

```
DynamicModule[{points = Transpose[{keys, opacities}]},
  ListLinePlot[points, 
    Epilog -> {PointSize[0.03], Point[points, VertexColors -> colors]},
    Prolog -> mesh[[1]],
    PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}},
    Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {"Intensity", "Opacity"},
    Filling -> Axis,
    ColorFunction -> ColorTransferFunction[colors, opacities, keys]]]
```

and got the result:

[image]

Comment: Please give a reference to the EditColorFunction you mention in the title.

Comment: @m_goldberg I have added the reference as per your request.

Comment: What constitutes a full answer? Is bg scalling and clipping the only requirement? Are locators related?

Comment: @Kuba Since, now I've implemented my basic requirement, I want the background to look similar to the first figure. If you wish to contribute further such as allowing the control points to move within the plot, create new points or delete points please let me know so that I can update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Texture`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html) just like Kuba this is the lazy-person way to solve your issue. I just used your `points` because I didn't want to be clever or anything. I'm using Kuba's `bg` and his correction for the standard [`AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html) because it was too much work to adapt `mesh`. If you want different aspect ratios you'll need to correct the `VertexTextureCoordinates` appropriately.

```
DynamicModule[{points = Transpose[{keys, opacities}]},
 ListLinePlot[
  points,
  Epilog -> {
    PointSize[0.03],
    Point[points,
     VertexColors -> colors
     ]
    },
  Prolog -> {
    Texture@bg,
    With[{l =
       Join[
        {
         {0, 0}
         },
        points,
        {
         {1, 0},
         {0, 0}
         }]},
     Polygon[l,
      VertexTextureCoordinates ->
       Map[{GoldenRatio, 1}*# &, l]
      ]
     ]
    },
  PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"Intensity", "Opacity"},
  Filling -> Axis,
  ColorFunction -> (Append[RandomColor[], RandomReal[]] &)]
 ]
```

Looks like this (note that I used `RandomColor` because I didn't know your `ColorTransferFunction`:

[image: example]

Comment: You need to compensate for AspectRatio too as the grid is distorted.

Comment: @Kuba this is true. If we assume it's `GoldenRatio` then your suggestion generally works. I do get a weird tiling gap though.

Comment: Generation artifact, feel free to use mine `bg`. You have that gap already on the borders.

Comment: @Kuba good plan. I was able to mostly fix things by changing the `PlotRange` of the `Graphics`, but I prefer the appearance of yours.

Answer (score 2):

```
bg = ImageResize[Image @ ArrayPad[{{1, .8}, {.8, 1}}, 5, "Periodic"], 400]
```

> [image]

> Firstly, I need the plot to be scaled accordingly as in fig 2.

Most of `*Plot*` functions have `1/GoldenRatio` as an `AspectRatio`, it affects the texture too, we need to compensate for that by adjusting `VertexTextureCoordinates`:

```
Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, .5]
  , AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
  , PlotRange -> 1
  , Frame -> True
  , Prolog -> {
        Texture[bg], Polygon[
            Scaled /@ {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}
          , VertexTextureCoordinates -> {
                {0, 0}, {GoldenRatio, 0}, {GoldenRatio, 1}, {0, 1}
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

> [image]

> Secondly, I want the control points to be colored according to the colors and opacities at those points and not a single color (blue) as I have got.

Solved by OP.

> [Optional: How can I remove the checkered background above the control points?]

Striaghtorward way is to apply `Texture` only to a polygon which consists of your points and bottom corners of the plot. But it is easier to control `VertexTextureCoordinates` for fixed rectangular polygon so the other way is to draw a white one over it:

```
... Prolog -> {
        ... 
      , White, Polygon[{{-1, .5}, {.5, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
    }
...
```

> [image]

Comment: you can also get most of the way there using the `points` the OP defined, e.g: `Prolog -> {
  Texture@Graphics@mesh[[1]],
  With[{l = Append[Prepend[points, {0, 0}], {1, 0}]},
   Polygon[l, VertexTextureCoordinates -> l]
   ]
  }`

Comment: @MB1965 started with that but somehow I couldn't make it perfectly non distorted grid. Could you share full code?

Comment: sure I'll post what I have.

Comment: @MB1965 otoh `VertexTextureCoordinates -> ({GoldenRatio, 1} # & /@ l)` seems to work.

Comment: @Kuba : Thanks for your answer. You got the background in a really simple way. And you are right that the golden ratio is really important here.   Is it explicitly mentioned in the documentation? I'm following MB1965's answer with your recommendation. Just one observation: despite having the original texture image a square, the final plot doesn't seem to maintain that aspect ratio. Is it also due to the same?