# Inserting a colored region in a plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm plotting my data points and I want to compare it to the experimentally accepted values. How can I apply the graphics option as shown below, I want to add a rectangular region to indicate the bound on the accepted values.[image]

```
ListLogLinearPlot[data2, AxesLabel -> {Subscript[n, s], r}, LabelStyle -> {Black, 13},
PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{0.94, 1}, Full}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium},
Prolog -> {LightBlue, Rectangle[{0.94, 0}, {0.97, 0.11}]}, Epilog -> {Thick, Black, Dashed, Line[{{0.94, 0.11}, {1, 0.11}}]}]
```

Comment: Related: [(72658)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72658/121)

Answer (score 3):

Generally you can use the [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) option and standard [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) primitives like [`Rectangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html) ([example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31889/121)) but for the given style you can use [`Filling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html) directives in [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) itself, like this:

```
Plot[
  {5, 8, 2 Sin[x] + x, x - 5 Sinc[x]}, {x, 0, 15}, 
  PlotStyle -> Join[{None, None}, ColorData[97, "ColorList"]], 
  Filling -> {1 -> {15, LightBlue}, {2 -> {12, Yellow}}}
]
```

[image]

The `Filling` method can be a little harder to set up but it scales well when changing `PlotRange` etc.

Comment: I have added the code that I have written but it's not working. I have also added a dashed line to indicate the bound on the y-axis, the shaded region that I want is a bound on the x-axis. The image that I have shown is just an example of what I want to achieve (colored region).

Comment: @mathemania If you are using a `ListPlot` variation the `Filling` method won't work directly, so I suggest you use `Prolog`.  Without a copy of your `data2` I can't evaluate your plot; perhaps you would include a minimal example?

Comment: I have used `Prolog`, not `Filling`. Also, `Epilog` doesn't work.

Comment: @mathemania Yes I see, but I don't want to have to craft dummy data just to run your code; please do that yourself.

Comment: My data points are in an excel file, maybe a linear function with 3 points would be enough just to show an example, maybe the domain is `x=1,2,3` and the values are `y=1,2,3` for a linear function `y=x`.